# "Registering" GVim in Windows XP

Tags: vim, windows-xp

*This is probably bordering off-topic-ness here, but not a lot of people on SuperUser use GVim, as opposed to here, so I'm leaving it here.*

The problem is simple - I'm using GVim 7.3. from *vim.org*, downloaded it in the form of archived binaries (the two archive files) like always and replaced the older version. However, I can't get Windows to *recognize* it and to associate a file extension to it.

From windows explorer go to, let's say, *.py* file, Open with ... / Browse / gvim.exe in its directory and ... *nothing.* Like it never happened.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behaviour? It's mighty annoying to have to open every file from within Vim manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default installer ("self-installing executable") from vim.org lets you register shell associations; this means you get an entry "open with vim" in every context menu from the explorer. Did you not use this file?

I'm looking at [this page](http://www.vim.org/download.php) and I'm thinking about [this download](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim73_46.exe).

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that file. However, I always liked using the self-installing binaries, because I sync. vim across several machines, and I usually just replace the old with the new one. I just tried the installer though, and although it gives me the "open with vim" option, I still can't use the "open with ..."/choose gvim/okey approach. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but it's a different way to edit with gvim from the context menu.

Create a .reg file with the contents below (adjusting your path to gvim.exe) and execute it.  Then whenever you right-click on a file in explorer you will have an "Open with GVIM" option.

```
REGEDIT4 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell] 
@="Open with GVIM" 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell] 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Open with &GVim] 
@="Open with GVIM" 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Open with &GVim\command] 
@="C:\\Vim\\gvim.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: Although it looks okey to me, for some reason it doesn't work ... throws out a "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Create an association in the Folder Options control panel" error when clicking upon OPen with Gvim.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying all kinds of tricks through the registry, but this solution works for me just fine.  I might add, I'm having the same issue on Windows 7.  Since Windows seems to be able to do the association with vim.exe just fine, and this is apparently tied to the file name, I moved vim.exe off as say vim.ex$ and made a copy of gvim.exe to vim.exe.  Cheap and easy way around this goofy problem, and I can't say I ever use vim.exe on purpose.